# Разбить массив по значениям

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения, php, сортировка

**Добрый день.**

Имеется многомерный массив, который нужно разбить по значению определенного поля.

```
array(
[0]=>
 [name]=>Ivan
 [sex]=>M
[1]=>
 [name]=>Gloria
 [sex]=>F
[2]
 [name]=>Bodua
 [sex]=>M
);
```

Нужно разбить этот массив по полю "sex"(пол).

И получить что то вроде:

```
array(
[men]=>
 [0]=>
  [name]=>Ivan
  [sex]=>M
 [2]
  [name]=>Bodua
  [sex]=>M
[women]=>
 [1]=>
  [name]=>Gloria
  [sex]=>F
);
```

**Вопросы:**

- Есть ли в php готовая функция позволяющая решить эту задачу?
- Если ответ на первый вопрос отрицательный: Есть ли решение, позволяющее решить эту задачу без переборки массива(его длина и кол-во полей будет в сотни раз больше данного примера).

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: [men, women](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/english-grammar-rules-for-possessive-plurals.html)

Comment: @Condensator что вы сделали с вопросом ? я же нормально отформатировал.... блин как тут правку отменить. 

@Condensator, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 5):

С учётом того, что `sex` принимает произвольные значения:

```
$ppl=array(
 array("name"=>"Ivan","sex"=>"M"),
 array("name"=>"Swimming Spaghetti Monster","sex"=>"N"),
 array("name"=>"John","sex"=>"M"),
 array("name"=>"Gloria","sex"=>"F"),
 array("name"=>"Flying Spaghetti Monster","sex"=>"N"),
 array("name"=>"Mary","sex"=>"F"),
);

$rc = array();
foreach( $ppl as $data )
{
    $rc[$data['sex']][] = $data;
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [M] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ivan
                    [sex] => M
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [sex] => M
                )
        )
    [N] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Swimming Spaghetti Monster
                    [sex] => N
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Flying Spaghetti Monster
                    [sex] => N
                )
        )
    [F] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Gloria
                    [sex] => F
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Mary
                    [sex] => F
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Используя [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php
$ppl=array(
 array("name"=>"Ivan","sex"=>"M"),
 array("name"=>"Gloria","sex"=>"F"),
 array("name"=>"Bodua","sex"=>"M"),
);

function males($entry) {
    return $entry['sex']=='M';
}

function females($entry) {
    return $entry['sex']=='F';
}

$out=array(
    "men"=>array_filter($ppl,'males'),
    "women"=>array_filter($ppl,'females'),
    );

echo json_encode($out,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

http://ideone.com/53fYfj

---

в следующий раз пожалуйста  форматируйте массивы как json или так, чтобы их скопипастить можно было.

Comment: Подскажите, а если нам заранее не известно, какие именно значения у поля sex?
Суть: у поля "sex"(пол) могут быть произвольные значения.
Задача та же- разбить массив по значениям поля "sex".

Заранее спасибо)